# This is not valid housing. What is valid housing?

Tags: terraria-console

I built myself a decent sized house with a basement and it said it wasn't valid housing.  So I built another one that is a very simple room with walls (dirt walls on the background, wood "walls") a door, two doors, a table, a chair, floors and light sources.  I've gone over and over it and made sure there are dirt walls everywhere.  It *still* says it's invalid housing.

I'm playing on Xbox 360.

Comment: Does it have a light source?

Comment: Did you place all the dirt walls yourself?

Comment: Yeah, I have a couple light sources.  I did place the dirt walls myself. I guess I'll keep making it bigger...

Comment: Does it have a table or workbench and a chair? Did you manage to create valid housing in the tutorial?

Comment: To whoever edited the title saying it was hard to find, it is the exact message you are presented with in the game.  The question has been viewed 5,800 times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your problem is this (based on you saying it has a basement):

If you dig into the ground at ALL and attempt to use the dirt wall as part of your wall, **Terraria thinks it's not valid housing**.

[image: Walls1]
[image: Walls2]

Take out that hammer and get rid of 100% dirt walls and replace it with whatever kind of wall you want.

Comment: This is probably what it was. My first house did have a basement, but the one I created afterwards that was just a simple square probably did have one row at the bottom of dirt wall that was already there.  Thanks.

Comment: Note, you can use dirt walls, but they have to be dirt walls you placed, the default dirt walls have to be removed, then replaced by your own walls, of whatever sort.

Answer (score 3):

[Terraria Wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home#Requirements) has a complete list of everything required to make something valid housing. Light source appears to be missing from your description in the question, I'd start there.

Comment: I forgot to mention it.  I have two torches and a tiki torch...

Comment: @Scott Then please correct your question.

Comment: I typically suggest that players use the [official wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/House) instead of the wikia one. The wikia one tends to have inaccurate or out of date information.